# MySQL: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 14"

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL code (that I've been testing with SQL Fiddle) for an assignment. The error I keep getting says there's a problem with `)` in line 14 `("REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)")`, but it says that even when there isn't a parentheses there. What's wrong with this code's syntax?

The error message says:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 14"

```
#Create the table definitions

CREATE TABLE Employee(
Fname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Minit       VARCHAR(1),
Lname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Ssn         CHAR(9)     PRIMARY KEY,
Bdate       DATE,
Address     VARCHAR(30),
Sex         CHAR(1),
Salary      NUMERIC(10,2),
Super_ssn   CHAR(9)     REFERENCES Department(Mgr_ssn),
Dno         INTEGER     REFERENCES Department(Dnumber),
);

CREATE TABLE Department(
Dname       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Dnumber     INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
Mgr_ssn     CHAR(9),
Mgr_start_date  DATE,
);

CREATE TABLE Dept_Locations(
Dnumber     INTEGER     REFERENCES Department,
Dlocation   VARCHAR(20),

PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber, Dlocation)
);

CREATE TABLE Project(
Pname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Pnumber     INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
Plocation   VARCHAR(20),
Dnum        INTEGER     REFERENCES Department,
);

CREATE TABLE Works_On(
Essn    CHAR(9)     REFERENCES Employee(Ssn),
Pno     INTEGER     REFERENCES Project(Pnumber),
Hours   NUMERIC(2,1),

PRIMARY KEY(Essn, Pno)
);

CREATE TABLE Dependent(
Essn        CHAR(9)     REFERENCES Employee(Ssn),
Dependent_name  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Sex     CHAR(1),
Bdate       DATE,
Relationship    VARCHAR(20),

PRIMARY KEY(Essn, Dependent_name)
);




#Insert records into the tables

INSERT INTO Employee
Values
('John',    'B','Smith',  '123456789','1965-01-09','731 Fondren, Houston,     TX','M',30000,'333445555',5),
('Franklin','T','Wong',   '333445555','1955-12-08','638 Voss, Houston, TX',       'M',40000,'888665555',5),
('Alicia',  'J','Zelaya', '999887777','1968-01-19','3321 Castle, Spring,     TX', 'F',25000,'987654321',4),
('Jennifer','S','Wallace','987654321','1941-06-20','291 Berry, Bellaire, TX', 'F',43000,'888665555',4),
('Ramesh',  'K','Narayan','666884444','1962-09-15','975 Fire Oak, Humble, TX','M',38000,'333445555',5),
('Joyce',   'A','English','453453453','1972-07-31','5631 Rice, Houston, TX',  'F',25000,'333445555',5),
('Ahmad',   'V','Jabbar', '987987987','1969-03-29','980 Dallas, Houston, TX', 'M',25000,'987654321',4),
('James',   'E','Borg',   '888665555','1937-11-10','450 Stone, Houston, TX',  'M',55000, NULL,      1);

INSERT INTO Department
Values
('Research',      5,'333445555','1988-05-22'),
('Administration',4,'987654321', '1995,01,01'),
('Headquarters',  1,'888665555','1981-06-19');

INSERT INTO Dept_Locations
Values
(1,'Houston'),
(4,'Stafford'),
(5,'Bellaire'),
(5,'Sugarland'),
(5,'Houston');

INSERT INTO Project
Values
('ProductX',        1,'Bellaire', 5),
('ProductY',        2,'Sugarland',5),
('ProductZ',        3,'Houston',  5),
('Computerization',10,'Stafford', 4),
('Reorganization', 20,'Houston',  1),
('Newbenefits',    30,'Stafford', 4);

INSERT INTO Works_On
Values
('123456789', 1,32.5),
('123456789', 2, 7.5),
('666884444', 3,40.0),
('453453453', 1,20.0),
('453453453', 2,20.0),
('333445555', 2,10.0),
('333445555', 3,10.0),
('333445555',10,10.0),
('333445555',20,10.0),
('999887777',30,30.0),
('999887777',10,10.0),
('987987987',10,35.0),
('987987987',30, 5.0),
('987654321',30,20.0),
('987654321',20,15.0),
('888665555',20,NULL);

INSERT INTO Dependent
Values
('333445555','Alice',    'F','1986-04-05','Daughter'),
('333445555','Theodore', 'M','1983-10-25','Son'),
('333445555','Joy',      'F','1958-05-03','Spouse'),
('987654321','Abner',    'M','1942-02-28','Spouse'),
('123456789','Michael',   'M','1988-01-04','Son'),
('123456789','Alice',    'F','1988-12-30','Daughter'),
('123456789','Elizabeth','F','1967-05-05','Spouse');




#Show values in all tables

SELECT *
FROM Employee;

SELECT *
FROM Department;

SELECT *
FROM Dept_Locations;

SELECT *
FROM Project;

SELECT *
FROM Works_On;

SELECT *
FROM Dependent; 




#Implement queries from Exercise 8.16
#a)
SELECT  E.Fname, E.Lname
FROM    Employee E, Works_On W, Project P
WHERE   E.Ssn = W.Essn  and
        P.Pnum = W.Pno  and
        E.Dno = 5       and
        P.Pname = 'ProjectX' and
        W.Hours > 10.0; 

#b)
SELECT  E.Fname, E.Lname
FROM    Employee E, Dependent D
WHERE   E.Ssn = D.Essn  and
        E.Fname = D.Dependent_name;

#c)
SELECT  Fname, Lname
FROM    Employee
WHERE   Super_ssn = (SELECT  Ssn
             FROM    Employee
             WHERE   Fname = 'Franklin' and
                     Lname = 'Wong');

#d)
SELECT   SUM(W.Hours)
FROM     Project P, Works_On W
WHERE    P.Pnumber = W.Pno
GROUP BY P.Pname;

#e)
SELECT  E.Fname, E.Lname
FROM    Employee E
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT  P.Pnumber
     FROM    Project P
     WHERE   P.Pnumber NOT IN
             (SELECT  W.Pno
              FROM    Works_On W
              WHERE   W.Essn = E.Ssn));

#f)
SELECT  E.Fname, E.Lname
FROM    Employee E
WHERE   EXISTS
        (E.Essn

         MINUS

         SELECT  [Distinct] W.Essn
         FROM    Works_On W
        );

#g)
SELECT   AVG(E.Salary)
FROM     Employee E, Department D
WHERE    E.Dno = D.Dnumber
GROUP BY D.Dname;

#h)
SELECT   AVG(Salary)
FROM     Employee
WHERE    Sex = 'F'
GROUP BY Sex;

#i)
SELECT  E.Fname, E.Lname, E.Address
FROM    Employee E
WHERE   EXISTS
        (SELECT  P.Pnumber
         FROM    Project P, Works On W
         WHERE   P.Pnumber = W.Pno     and
                 W.Essn = E.Ssn        and
                 Plocation = 'Houston' and
                 NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT  Dl.Dnumber
                  FROM    Dept_Locations Dl
                  WHERE   Dl.Dlocation = 'Houston' and
                          E.Dno = Dl.Dnumber));

#j)
SELECT  E.Lname
FROM    Employee E, Department De
WHERE   De.Mgr_ssn = E.Ssn and
        NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT  Dp.Essn
         FROM    Dependent Dp
         WHERE   Dp.Essn = E.Ssn);




#Drop all tables

DROP TABLE Dependent      RESTRICT;
DROP TABLE Works_On       RESTRICT;
DROP TABLE Project        RESTRICT;
DROP TABLE Dept_Locations RESTRICT;
DROP TABLE Department     RESTRICT;
DROP TABLE Employee       CASCADE;
```

Comment: If you ref a table you need to define it before. Put  `Department` on top.

Answer (score 5):

You have a comma after `Dno   INTEGER     REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)`, remove that comma so it looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
Fname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Minit       VARCHAR(1),
Lname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Ssn         CHAR(9)     PRIMARY KEY,
Bdate       DATE,
Address     VARCHAR(30),
Sex         CHAR(1),
Salary      NUMERIC(10,2),
Super_ssn   CHAR(9)     REFERENCES Department(Mgr_ssn),
Dno         INTEGER     REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
);
```

In fact, do that for all the tables you are creating.

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
Dname       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Dnumber     INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
Mgr_ssn     CHAR(9),
Mgr_start_date  DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Project(
Pname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Pnumber     INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
Plocation   VARCHAR(20),
Dnum        INTEGER     REFERENCES Department
);
```